# Generating a const char ** to return

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

I have a method that receives a `char **` as an argument in order to parse and construct a proper inner object.

```
  void  build (const char*  values[], const int amount=3) 
  {
       //..parse values and create instance of an inner field..
  }
```

It is constant, because I just want to use those values and I don't need to modify them at all. This works pretty much fine.

Now I want to be able to code a method that returns to me a `const char **` in a way that I am able to use this returned value in the previously declared method. At first, I got the values needed from the instance of my class, converted them to string and put them in an array and returned it, but it was complaining that I was returning  a pointer to a local variable. So I thought of using another field to hold this pointer, I created `char ** values`.  Then I realized that I would need to allocate the memory for the value it points to, so I went trough with it.   Currently the method I'm describing looks something like:

```
 const char** getValues()
 {
   string var;

   var = toString(point.zone);
   values[0]= new  char[var.length()+1](); 
   strcpy(values[0], var.c_str());       

   var = toString(point.easting);
   values[1]= new char[var.length()+1]();
   strcpy(values[1],var.c_str());

   var = toString(point.northing);
   values[2]= new char[var.length()+1]();
   strcpy(values[2],var.c_str());

   return values;

 }
```

But at the moment this will complain because `char ** values` is not constant. But if I make it constant,the `strcpy` will complain about the opposite. If I dont return it constant then I cant us it in other function.  I need help fixing this problem. Any help is deeply appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Too much ifs and buts. Oh..!!!

Comment: How do you declare/allocate `values`?

Comment: its a private field of the object: `char * values[3]`

Comment: @H2CO3 So you like explicitly `const_cast`ing every time you use a non-modifying STL algorithm? Please stay away from purely subjective comments like `Another reason to agree with Mr Torvalds on C++ being crap.`. This is SO.

Comment: @Hindol I don't really program in C++, rather C.

Comment: @H2CO3: The essentials of type safety are language independent.

Comment: @BenVoigt Well, yes, but I was reacting to the "Are you const_casting everything" part of the question...

Comment: @BenVoigt Also, you don't get the point. If the internals/implementation needs to modify a data type, why not allocate it dynamically, then modify it (i. e. `char *var = malloc(100);`)? But, if you still want the user of the object to see it as const, readonly, however you call it, you should be able to return a non-const value from a function returning const. I. e. it's not a problem if you don't modify something mutable. Only mutating immutable objects (i. e. returning/passing a `const char *` where a `char *` is expected) counts as an error.

Comment: @H2CO3 Sorry if I seemed aggressive. It is just that I hate _C++-hatred_.

Comment: @H2CO3: You're the one not understanding the types involved here.  a `char*` can be returned as a `const char*`.  A `char**` can be returned as a `const char* char*` or a `char* const*`.  But a `char**` cannot be returned as a `const char**`.  That is not making the return value more `const` than it was, it's making it *different*.  And this is not unique to C++, the same argument [applies equally to C](http://ideone.com/DC5Yy).

Comment: @BenVoigt Now I see. The problem is the double pointer - still my statement holds for a simple char pointer, right?

Comment: @Hindol I removed my comment, and also sorry if I hurt you with that, but really, this was just a comment, with no intent agains anybody, and it's my honest opinion...

Comment: @H2CO3: I think you're right about how a single pointer behaves, but a single pointer has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: @BenVoigt yes, just realized that, sorry for the ignorance... (anyway, I do understand type safety.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got a compilation error because you try to strcpy to a `char const*` directly.
You should instead strcpy to a `char *` and assign this pointer back to the values[].

See the modified code below for a simple solution:

```
 const char** getValues()
 {
   string var;
   char* p;

   var = toString(point.zone);
   p = new  char[var.length()+1](); 
   strcpy(p, var.c_str());       
   value[0] = p; // now you can assign char* to char const* without compilation error

   var = toString(point.easting);
   p = new char[var.length()+1]();
   strcpy(p, var.c_str());
   value[1] = p;

   var = toString(point.northing);
   p = new char[var.length()+1]();
   strcpy(p,var.c_str());
   value[2] = p;

   return values;

 }
```

Comment: compilation error is not there, it is because `values` is declared as a `char * values[]` and I'm returning `const char **`

Comment: Using the above code, you can now define values[] as `const char* values[]`. If your `values` should actually be `char *`, casting `char**` to const char ** is ok.

Comment: This actually solves the problem in question so Ill mark it as an answer

Answer (score 2):

One main point, why are you making your life complicated with `char**` instead of using `std::string` or `std::vector<std::vector<char>>` where appropriate?

I mean, if you're using C++ as your tags seem to indicate, then why not USE C++ and not C.

This will make your life much easier.

Another thing:

A `const char**` is a pointer to pointer to char that is const.  Meaning you cannot alter the `char`.  If you want to alter use `char**`.

Allocation is another point about your code, how are you allocating memory for your `char**`?

These are added complexities that you shouldn't need to have in C++, if you just use what I said above.

Comment: +1, anything other than using higher level features of the language will be a pain (manage the resources for starters)

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for `const char* const* const`, where not only the data pointed to, but the pointers themselves, are constant.

There is an implicit conversion from `char**` to `const char* const*`.  The rules of covariance forbid the conversion from `char**` to `const char**`, however, because a `const char**` is writable (you can store a new pointer), and operations which write to a collection are not safe for covariance.  Take a look:

```
const char* a = "a literal"; // ok, literal is read-only, so const char* is good.
char* b;
char* c[] = { &b };
const char** d = c; // this step is illegal under the current rules
*d = &a;
*b = 'A'; // this would write to a string literal, causing an access violation
```

Notice that if the conversion were allowed, you could write to a `const` object without breaking type safety, which wouldn't be safe at all.

With `const char* const* d = c`, the following step (`*d = &a`) is already illegal, so there is no hole in the type system.

Comment: Strange. This answer is not technically incorrect - +1 for compensation.